# How to pass array parameters through a function, to then can bind_param() arrays to add to a database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli

So i am working on a project where when you select a English football league, e.g Premier League, Championship, League One..It will `include 'premier_league.php';`or what ever league is selected, it is included. The page consists of a form, that has a row of 10 `<input...>` & `<select><option>`. Them 10 items make up one row/fixture. As the number of rows vary up to 10 fixtures for the premier league or 12 for the championship. The max number of rows is determined by how many teams are in the specific league then divided by 2. With the number of rows being so many, i have looped through the data. so the page that is called up, in this case, `premier_league.php` is set up like so...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="btn btn-medium btn-success"><br><br>
<?php

$leaguelist = '<option disabled>Please select team</option>';
if ($league_var == NULL) {
    $leaguelist .= '<option "disabled"><strong>Please Select a League Table</strong></h1>';
} else {
    $league_table = get_table($league_var);
    foreach ($league_table as $rows) {    

    $leaguelist .= '<option>'.htmlspecialchars($rows['team']).'</option>';
    }
}
$needed_rows = ceil(count(get_table($league_var)) / 2);
for($i=1; $i <= $needed_rows; $i++){
?>
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][home]" id="" style="width:175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][home-score]" class="edit_league_input" value="">
vs
<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][away-score]" class="edit_league_input" name="" value="">
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][away]" id="" style="175px">
<?=$leaguelist?>
</select>
<input type="date" name="result[<?=$i?>][date]" style="width:150px;">
<input type="time" name="result[<?=$i?>][kickoff]" style="width:90px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="result[<?=$i?>][on-tv]" value="Yes" style="margin:-10px 5px 0px 5px;">on T.v
<input type="text" name="result[<?=$i?>][channel]" value="" placeholder="Channel..." style="width:100px;">
<select name="result[<?=$i?>][result]" id="" style="width:125px;">
<option value="">Match Choice...</option>
<option value="HT">Half Time</option>
<option value="FT">Full Time</option>
<option value="P">Postponed</option>
</select>
<br>
<?php
}
```

**I was helped with this code and was advised to set up the page like this.** Meanwhile, my prepared statement for the MySQLi query was coded like...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fixtures` 
(`home`, `home-score`, `away-score`, `away`, `kickoff`, `on-tv`, `channel`, `league`, `result`, `date`)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST['result'] as $fixture) {
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['home']);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $fixture['hs']);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $fixture['as']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['away']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['kickoff']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['on-tv']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['channel']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['league']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['result']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fixture['date']);
$stmt->execute();
```

I think i can begin to see the start of the binding process...taking the `..['home']` and binding to the first **?**, the `$fixture['hs']` to the 2nd **?** but i can only guess is that would only be one row it binds? but what if i add 4? 8? or all 12 fixtures how would it bind all them?...

Someone suggested using a different piece of code and that is ...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($h); $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `fixtures` (`home`, `home-score`, `away-score`, `away`, `kickoff`, `on-tv`, `channel`, `league`, `result`, `date`)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $home[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $hs[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $as[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $away[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $time[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $tv[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $channel[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $league[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $result[$i]);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date[$i]);
$success = $stmt->execute();

    if ($success === false) {
        echo $stmt->errno . ": " . $stmt->error;
    }
}
```

now this, i can see how in theory it would work.. The `[$i]` is a representative of the row the loop is on, but, even still, im struggling to work out how to put this, if its meant to be, in a function.. plus how to bind_param arrays, and finally enter the data to the database.

**1)** If you feel that i should change the code, any of it, please say, help and advise where & what you feel i need to change.

**2)** But mainly, **I ask...** How should/would I bind an array to parameters to pass a function to `INSERT` multiple rows of data to a database.

I just want to say, i have searched here and online, and the things i have found, i just can't figure out how to implement it into my code to make the whole thing work im afraid :(

Comment: Why don't you ask from your other account?

Comment: my other account? i dont have one? i think i know what you mean though. My brother has an account and he been banned from asking questions, so since im helping him with a few design plans and basic code, i thought while he is stressing, trying to figure it out how to get the thing to work, id set up an account and ask for him

Comment: *Please*, I beg you, don't. Or at least devise something not *that* silly.

Comment: i dont get you, how is what silly? do you think we're making this up? :S im just trying to help my brother, thats all.. and hopefully someone can help us, if you want to think we're *upto something* thats fine but we are'nt and  dont know how to convince you otherwise so im not going to bother trying

Comment: All right, just get this account banned as well, if you wish. I don't really care. Just curious

Comment: All I'm trying to do is help Richard out. Clearly seemed to be more hassle that its worth! plus, I don't mean to offend or anything but if you don't really care why did you comment?